What is the difference between disabling chip with directly disconnect power and with enable pin?
Often in a chip, it contains a pin with the name Shutdown, Chip Enabled, Reset, or similar.
Compared to directly disconnecting the chip power to ground (VCC/VDD to zero), what is the difference?

Very large difference.
First, Reset does not belong in a group with the other three.  Reset is an operating function that requires that the chip be powered up and enabled.
As for the others, the difference is that when a chip is powered, its output states are defined by its inputs, including control inputs such as Shutdown and Enable.  An output state might be a high impedance such as with a tri-state device with the outputs disabled, but even that will have a leakage current spec.  Also, inputs might still have a bias voltage or current that can affect whatever is driving them.  TTL was famous for this.
When power is removed, all bets are off.  You don't know how inputs and outputs will appear to external signals.  Medium impedance to VCC, to GND, to both, something with a semiconductor junction in the path so the apparent impedance varies depending on voltage polarity and level, etc.  To be clear, a chip that is shut down due to a control pin, and one that is completely powered off, can be two very different things.

Well, as long as we're talking about Reset with MCU-like semantics and not the one in a SR flip-flop, it does conceptually belong in the same group. There are many ICs where holding Reset asserted keeps the chip in a well-defined nearly-shut-down/disabled state. Of course, it depends on the specific IC whether this is allowed or a great idea; check the datasheet as always.

There are many Many MANY chips that are not microcontrollers.

Oh, if that's what you meant, of course, that's obviously a fair point. What I was hinting at is that these days, hobbyists (who would ask basic questions like this one) are much more likely to be playing with something that at least resembles a MCU in the handling of Reset than with other kinds of chips. But I see that my comments aren't really adding anything of value to your nice answer, so I'll delete them soon.

Leave them in; they make a fair point.  However, uC's are famous for having one pin do 17 functions, so I don't think their interpretation of what a Reset function is is representative of all logic devices.  I see them as the exception, not the rule.  And while they seem to be everywhere in everything, keep in mind that the highest-selling IC of all time is an analog part (With a Reset input).

For one, a chip in shutdown will draw more quiescent current than a chip that's fully disconnected. It's usually quite small quiescent current, though; in chips designed for very low-power applications, the shutdown current can be well below a microamp.
Mostly, the shutdown feature provides a very simple way to turn the chip off. Removing power entirely would require an additional chip in the form of at minimum a discrete transistor, more likely a load switch. The shutdown feature can be thought of, in many cases, as essentially just a built-in load switch. Especially in the case of certain types of dc-dc converter, this allows using the main switching transistor itself to cut power, so you don't have to have an additional transistor in series (which will lower efficiency slightly due to its additional Rdson).
The shutdown feature also typically means that the chip will not get power through its inputs when it's meant to be turned off. On many, perhaps even most ICs, a high level on any input while Vcc is disconnected will weakly power the chip through ESD protection diodes. This is undesirable, and very easy to do accidentally. Using a shutdown feature avoids this.

Last paragraph, very important. This is what makes cold-sparing so difficult.

@Mattman944 What is "cold-sparing"?

@jonathanjo Having a backup subsystem turned off, ready to turn on if the primary subsystem fails.
